# Vim splits the window horizontally whenever i switch between buffers if i didn't get the data written to the disk first

Tags: buffers

I currently use ctrlp to navigate between buffers in vim ,
but whenever i try to switch to another buffer it automatically splits the current window horizontally into two windows .

In order to avoid this or open the new buffer in a whole window i have to first write to the initial buffer at the disk then open ctrlp and switch to the second buffer .

How to get vim to open a new buffer in a full window rather then a split one ?

Comment: Do you have `:set hidden` or no?

Comment: @BLayer explicitly stated

Comment: @D.BenKnoble thanks that did work out .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you just need to `:set hidden`. Without it, you cannot "hide" a buffer with unedited contents; it must be written or wiped. My guess is CtrlP detects this case and splits open instead.